# python: remove given xml tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, findall

Good morning,
I tried to remove the tag Heading but i didn't succeed .
My code is below, it doesn't generate error but doesn't drop the heading tag.
Thank you in advance,

```
<xml>
   <Heading>
     <tmp> a1</tmp>
     <tmp2> a2 </tmp2>
   </Heading>
   <data>
      <db> Id0123 </db>
      <db1>
         <x1> abc </x1>
         <x2> dze </x2>
     </db1>
     <db2>
         <x1> abc2 </x1>
     </db2>
   </data>
</xml>
```

**Expected_Output**

```
<xml>
   <data>
      <db> Id0123 </db>
      <db1>
           <x1> abc </x1>
           <x2> dze </x2>
      </db1>
      <db2>
           <x1> abc2 </x1>
      </db2>
   </data>
</xml>
```

**code**

```
xmlTree = parse("File.xml")
for xe in xmlTree.findall("xml"): 
    for elementx in xe.findall('Heading'): 
        xe.remove(elementx)
```

Comment: When you print `xe` what do you get? What is `xmlTree`? There isn't an `'xml'` tag in your data... PLease read [mcve].  We need to be able to copy and paste from your question and test.

Comment: @wwii thank you for your comment. I have edited my original post, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

With your xml example, find the elements you want to remove and iterate over them.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xmlTree = ET.fromstring(s)
with open('foo.xml') as f:
    xmlTree = ET.parse(f)
for el in xmlTree.getiterator('xml'):
    for thing in el.getiterator('Heading'):
        print(thing.tag,thing.attrib)
        el.remove(thing)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I got this error **AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'remove'**